# Isn't grails-app/conf on the classpath anymore for grails 2.1.1?

Tags: grails

Have such Bootstrap:

```java
class BootStrap {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    def init = { servletContext ->                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      def file = servletContext.getResource("ehcache.xml")                                                                                                                                                                                     
       println "+++ ${file}"                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    def destroy = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Application contains `ehcache.xml` file in grails-app/conf directory, but it prints

+++ null

during bootstrapping. What's the prob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`servletContext.getResource` doesn't look on the classpath, it looks under `web-app`. Try `grailsApplication.classLoader.getResource` instead (this may require a class-level `def grailsApplication` outside the `init` closure, I'm not sure).

Alternatively, move the file to `web-app/WEB-INF` and then

```
servletContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml')
```

should work.

Comment: Ok, Iah. Thanks for your response. It's apparenly shows me now `ehcache.xml` sitting in `jar:file:/home/archer/.grails/ivy-cache/org.apache.camel/camel-cache/bundles/camel-cache-2.9.4.jar!/ehcache.xm`
But how should I make sure that `grails-app/conf/ehcache.xml` is on the classpath? I doubt, as EhChace does not find it during loading (I've enabled debug for that).

Comment: @archer any solution based on `ClassLoader.getResource` will give you the first match it finds on the classpath, I suggest you try the approach of moving the file to `web-app/WEB-INF` instead, that way you can reliably refer to that specific file. Or try putting it in `src/java` instead of `grails-app/conf`

Comment: ok thank you. Seems this is my bad somehow. Actual issue is that ehacache.xml seems ignored during startup. Trrying to find out the reason.

Comment: @archer this is getting beyond my expertise now I'm afraid. If you don't get any other useful answers here try the Grails `user` mailing list/nabble forum.